# What language was the first to implement exception handling?

Tags: exception

This question is not a technical but a historical one. I was just thinking today that I've also thought of Java as the "first" language to use exception handling, until I realized that my reason for thinking this way is probably because Java was the first language *I* encountered that used it, but I had no historical data to back up that conclusion. Nowadays exception handling is commonplace in all modern languages, so I'm just wondering: does anyone know when it first started being widely used? And what language was the first to start using it?

Comment: java wasn't the first to have almost anything

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Programming Languages: Principles and Practice*, 2nd edition, by Kenneth C. Louden (a notable textbook on programming languages) notes that "Exception handling was pioneered by the language PL/I in the 1960s and significantly advanced in CLU in the 1970s. However, it was only in the 1980s and early 1990s that design questions were largely resolved" (283).

Comment: [Corbató](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_J._Corbató) makes a passing reference to the use of `ON` conditions in a 1969 Datamation article entitled [_PL/I As a Tool for System Programming_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080206153039/http://home.nycap.rr.com/pflass/PLI/plisprg.html), written about the [Multics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics) team's experiences with their "temporary" PL/I compiler, at that time already 5 years into its life.

Comment: Louden apparently failed to recognize that Lisp 1.5 already in 1961 had the ERRORSET function which had the same effect as the CATCH function added to MacLisp in 1972, and that MacLisp in 1966 added the ERR function which together with the ERRSET function (which was a renamed ERRORSET) supported dynamic non-local exits. So what we know today as exception handling (try/catch/throw) was already present in MacLisp around 1966. But PL/I indeed inspired the Common Lisp condition system.

Answer (score 15):

Exception handling really goes back to even before programming languages; at first, it was a hardware mechanism for trapping error conditions (those that caused an execution halt) and optionally branching to a subroutine.

For example, the VAX CPU could detect when a virtual address that had no physical mapping was accessed, and call into a subroutine that either loaded the appropriate page from swap, or halted the program. The mechanism is essentially the same in modern processors (look up "translation lookaside buffer"). So in a sense the first language to have exceptions was assembly.

The earliest structured languages to have exceptions appear to be PL/I and CLU (see Mipadi above).

Comment: Hardware traps/interrupts are different from exception processing.  Traps/interrupts generally either get nested on the stack and allow processing to continue undisturbed, or else they kill a thread and its stack.  It's very rare for hardware traps/interrupts to be used to disturb program flow with any paradigm remotely resembling C++/C#/vb/.net/etc. exceptions.

Answer (score 10):

[CLU](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-561.pdf) had exception handling in the early 1970s.

Comment: Actually, according to the paper you linked to, work on CLU's exception handling started in 1975 and it had stabilized by 1977.  So *late* 1970's would be a better characterization.

Answer (score 7):

C++ had exceptions before Java did.

Answer (score 4):

I can remember using exception handlers in Xerox's Mesa language in ... um ... 1984.  The language existed well before then.  Mesa had an interesting exception model.  In addition to propagating and handling an exception in the normal way, a handler could "resume" an exception, causing execution to return from the "throw" statement.

Comment: The ability to resume an exception actually exists in Windows exceptions, though it's not a well known/used thing...

Comment: @Matthew.  So perhaps this is where Windows copied it from :-)

Comment: See Stroustrup's discussion of 'terminate vs resume' semantics in "Design and Evolution of C++".  The Cedar system which was built using Mesa and initially had a number of 'resume' exceptions, but over time they were all eliminated in favour of 'terminate' semantics. Eventually, Cedar had just one exception left that used 'resume' semantics, and on further review, that was removed too.

Comment: That sounds like (what Common Lisp calls) conditions, which are more generic than exceptions.  But upon further inspection, it looks like PL/I offers the same feature.  Which raises the question: what language was the first to implement Java/C++/C#/Python/Ruby-style exceptions (and not Mesa/Lisp/PL/I-style restartable conditions)?

Comment: Answer to my own question: possibly CLU (from Liskov's paper, linked above): "We considered and rejected the resumption model present in both PL/I and Mesa because it was complex and also because we believed that most of the time, termination was what was wanted. Furthermore, if resumption were wanted, it could be simulated by passing a procedure as an argument (although closures would be useful here)."

Answer (score 3):

Algol 68's "transput" had "event" handling, but it wasn't streamline enough for the programmer to extent it.

The ALGOL 68 *standard* uses event routines extensively in the "standard transput" (stdio) to manage the various events that arise when data is read (or written) to a file or external device. The built in "on event" routines are:

- on char error, on format error, on line
  end, on logical file end, on page end,
  on physical file end & on value error

In 1983 Proposals were being accepted to allowing a programmer defined their own exceptions. AFAIK none of these proposals were accepted by the United Nation's IFIP.

However the Russians *standards body* "GOST" did standardize exception handling near the end of Glasnost/Гласност in the standard ["GOST 27975-88 Programming language ALGOL 68 extended - Язык программирования АЛГОЛ 68 расширенный"](http://vak.ru/lib/exe/fetch.php/book/gost/pdf/gost-27975-88.pdf)

GOST 27975-88 used the additional keywords: MODULE, PUB, POSTLUDE, NEST, EGG, ON, EXCEPTION and RAISE.

Here are the original UK proposals:

1. [AB49.1983-May](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1061780.1061786) : "A Proposal for Exception Handling in ALGOL 68", by [C. H. Lindsey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Lindsey) - Pages: 10 - 15
2. [AB49.1983-May](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1061780.1061787) : "An Exception-Handling Mechanism for ALGOL 68", by [Martyn     Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyn_Thomas) - Pages: 16 - 17

They appear similar to what is now implemented in [python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)).

Lindsey's Example:

```
    EXCEPTION singular = new exception ; # EXCEPTION la a new mode #
    PROC gauss = ( REF [ , ] REAL a. REF [ ] REAL rhs ) VOID :
          COMMENT a procedure to solve a set of simultaneous
                      equations COMMENT
          BEGIN C the usual algorithm for gaussian elimination which, at some
                              point, may discover that a is singular C ;
                   IF C it makes this discovery C
                   THEN RAISE singular
                   FI;
                   C rest of algorithm CO
          END;
```

Exceptions bulitin were: time exhausted, space exhausted, arithmetic error, bounds error, scope error, transput impossible, file end, char error, value error and format error

Martyn Thomas's Example:

```
    BEGIN
      on ( overflow , overflow handler ) ;
      on ( bound check, boundcheckhandler ) ;
      C body of the closed - clause C
    EXIT
    overflow handler:
            C handle overflow exceptions C
    EXIT
    bound check handler:
        C handle bound check C
    END
```

BTW: The Soviet's Space Shuttle [Buran/Буран](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_(spacecraft)) completed one unmanned spaceflight in 1988, the automatic landing system was written in Algol.  The Amercian's still deploy numerous bits of military/space apparatus in [Jovial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOVIAL) (Algol 58), and this *may* contain exception handling from the 1950s.  Anyone got any ideas on this?...

Wikipedia: [Buran_(spacecraft)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_(spacecraft)): The shuttle orbited the Earth twice in 206 minutes of flight. It performed an automated landing on the shuttle runway at [Baikonur Cosmodrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikonur_Cosmodrome) where, despite a lateral wind speed of 61.2 kilometres (38.0 mi) /hour, it landed only 3 metres (9.8 ft) laterally and 10 metres (33 ft) longitudinally from the target.

Comment: Were those more like OOP exceptions, or signals/traps (also sometimes confusingly called hardware exceptions)?  One thing that sets OOP exceptions apart from other earlier concepts is that earlier concepts like signals/traps would either clear the stack entirely or push things onto it before processing the exceptional condition, while OOP exceptions pop the stack back to specific points.

Answer (score 3):

The `errorset` function in Lisp 1.5, described in a 1962 reference manual, is an early form of exception handling. In *The Evolution of Lisp*, Gabriel and Steele make these remarks, evidently getting the name of the operator slightly wrong and simplifying its syntax (P. 9-10):

> In Lisp 1.5, certain built-in functions might signal errors, when given incorrect arguments, for
>   example. Signaling an error normally resulted in program termination or invocation of a debugger.
>   Lisp 1.5 also had the function
>   ERRSET
>   , which was useful for controlled execution of code that
>   might
>   cause an error. The special form
>
> ```
> (errset form)
> ```
>
> evaluates
>   form
>   in a context in which errors do not terminate the program or enter the debugger.
>   If
>   form
>   does not cause an error,
>   ERRSET
>   returns a singleton list of the value. If execution of
>   form
>   does cause an error, the
>   ERRSET
>   form quietly returns
>   NIL
>   .
>
> MacLisp added the function
>   ERR
>   , which signals an error. If
>   ERR
>   is invoked within the dynamic
>   context of an
>   ERRSET
>   form, then the argument to
>   ERR
>   is returned as the value of the
>   ERRSET
>   form.
>
> Programmers soon began to use
>   ERRSET
>   and
>   ERR
>   not to trap and signal errors but for more
>   general control purposes (dynamic non-local exits). Unfortunately, this use of
>   ERRSET
>   also quietly
>   trapped unexpected errors, making programs harder to debug. A new pair of primitives,
>   CATCH
>   and
>   THROW
>   , was introduced into MacLisp in June 1972 so that
>   ERRSET
>   could be reserved for its intended
>   use of error trapping.

The [manual](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~rountev.1/6341/pdf/Manual.pdf) has, of course, the details, on Page 34, section "6.4 The Cons Counter and Errorset".

It looks like `errorset` interacts with the "cons counter", a memory allocation watchdog. The user of `errorset` must specify an integer value `n`, which specifies how many cons cells can be allocated in the protected computation before a trap will occur.

The description ends with these words:

> If 
>   an 
>   error 
>   occurs 
>   inside 
>   of 
>   an 
>   errorset, 
>   then 
>   the 
>   value 
>   of 
>   errorset 
>   is 
>   NIL. 
>   If  vari- 
>   ables 
>   bound 
>   outside 
>   of 
>   the 
>   errorset 
>   have 
>   not 
>   been 
>   altered 
>   by 
>   using 
>   cset 
>   or 
>   set, 
>   and 
>   if  no 
>   damage 
>   has 
>   been 
>   done 
>   by 
>   pseudo-functions, 
>   it may be 
>   possible 
>   to 
>   continue  computation 
>   in 
>   a different 
>   direction 
>   when 
>   one 
>   path 
>   results 
>   in an 
>   error.

This clearly shows that the construct is suitable for locally trapping an error, and then recovering (continuing computation "in a different direction when one path results in an error").

ANSI Common Lisp "conditions" show a lot of inspiration from the PL/I "conditions" system. However, PL/I was [first available in 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I#Early_history), a few years after Lisp 1.5's `errset`. The [first PL/I reference manual](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_ibm360pliCpecificationsJul65_11929709/page/n1/mode/2up/search/condition), dated 1965, does already describe ON-units and conditions.

Comment: Even the first edition of the Lisp 1.5 Programmer's Manual from July 14, 1961 has exactly the same ERRORSET function (not ERRSET as claimed in Steele's paper). MacLisp evolved from Lisp 1.5 around 1965 and included the ERRORSET function, renamed to ERRSET; in addition it had a function called ERR. The pair ERRSET/ERR supported dynamic non-local exits long before CATCH/THROW were added (and even much longer before the Common Lisp Condition System or its origins in the Lisp Machine). So it's pretty clear that MacLisp had the first true exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

We should not forget C which had `setjmp(3)` and `longjmp(3)` in the 1970's.

And before that, Basic, with `on error goto...`

I never saw an algol68 implementation, but I heard it had the kitchen sink...

Comment: I've heard that PL/1 was big and complex for its day, it probably had exceptions, meaning they could be quite old, mid 1960's. COBOL appears to have them now, but I wonder when they were added..

Comment: Oh, I thought of one more. Quite possibly one of the 999 versions of Lisp was first with an exception-like mechanism.

Comment: I wrote PL/1 on the VAX in 1986, and it had exception handling built in to the language.

Comment: I was really referring to the type of exception handling that can be caught, which I don't believe is really the case with `on error goto`. I'm sure you could emulate that using global variables, but AFAIK you can't pass out different exception "types." And it's the same with `setjmp`/`longjmp`. Those are really just `goto` commands, not "exception handling" as we think of it today.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree wrt setjmp and longjmp, as they exchange a value, which can be a cookie for an arbitrarily elaborate exception typing system. I think you might be more right about basic. Both are clearly exceptions, though, and not sentinel value returns...

Comment: @SoaperGEM: while basics on error goto obviously doesn't report details about the exception, I don't think that's as critical as the exception itself -- for most custom exceptions the details are only there in order to faciltate fixing bugs, and they are still quite useful.

Comment: I would suggest that the combination of setjmp/longjmp with a static variable whose value is unique for each thread would be adequate to provide exception handling.  Any routine which will have to do anything special with exceptions that bubble up to it would copy the static variable to the stack, copy the output of setjmp() to the static variable, and continue.  On exit (normal or abnormal), reload the static variable from the stack.

Comment: Many frameworks implemented exception handling using setjmp/longjmp. E.g. the Cocoa framework's NS_DURING/NS_HANDLER macros on older MacOS versions. Also C++ libraries from before that got exceptions. setjmp and longjmp by itself is not exception handling, but it is a part of implementing it.

Comment: @DigitalRoss ... re: "bloated" ... In March 25, 2000 with Andrew Ferguson's "The History of Computer Programming Languages", the Algol68 terse "monster" finally became kitchen-sink "bloated"... cf. [reddit: Go vs Algol68](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/a481l/so_to_get_back_to_the_point_go_vs_algol68_tbh_i)

Comment: `setjmp`  and `longjmp` were likely inspired by non-local goto mechanism already present in BCPL, which is historically recognized as a predecessor language that inspired B.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding COBOL's support for exception handling: Classic (I/O and arithmetic) exception handling has been around since at least the 1968 COBOL standard. OO exception handling was added to COBOL in the 2002 standard.