# str.find(sub[, start[, end]]) returns -1 when sub is not found in Python

Tags: python

I understand that the method:

```
str.find
```

will return a -1 if the sub is not found.

Is there a specific reason why the value -1 is used?  Is it arbitrary or is it useful to have a -1 for some further calculation involving strings?

I'm trying to understand the reasoning if any for the choice of that value.

Comment: I suspect the behaviour is inherited from string-find functions in earlier languages that would have had to return an integer (rather than, say, `None`) due to static typing. Other contemporary languages like Java and JavaScript have the same behaviour. FWIW I have never found it ‘useful’ in the way many of Python's string indexing edge cases are.

Comment: In general, use `str.index` instead; it raises an error if it can't find the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of research on this question and have come up with the following.  As has been said in a number of the answers here, in traditional programing languages or early programming languages coders have dealt with errors by having functions return special values. The consequence of this however is that any other code that calls a function that returns some value has to check whether a value was returned and deal with it specifically.

In newer languages such as Python, we can raise an exception when we are unable to produce a result that is consistent with a function's specifications.  While exception handling was evident in languages back in the 1960s.  The following post explains that it wasn't until the 80s and 90s that design questions were largely resolved.  [What language was the first to implement exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449951/what-language-was-the-first-to-implement-exception-handling)

Thus my conclusion is that until the advanced implementation of exception handling that could deal with error generation in a myriad of ways, the primitive method of returning some arbitrary value, was by and large all that could be accomplished until more advanced methods were created.

Answer (score 3):

[`string.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find):

> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in `s[start:end]`. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for *start* and *end* and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Since it's supposed to return an index, it makes sense to return -1 when the substring is not found (this is usually the behavior in most programming languages as well).

If you prefer that an `Exception` is raised instead, use the [`string.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) method.

Answer (score 0):

The **find** method returns the zero-based index of "*sub*" in the given string. That's a convention used in many other languages like Java, C#, and JavaScript. If "*sub*" cannot be found then -1 is returned.

I really can't think of any other reason for this behavior other than common sense and convention.

Answer (score 0):

Returning -1 when a string search comes up empty is based on the fact that returning 0 is an ambiguous return value in case of 0-indexed strings... consider the following example:

```
# returns 0 (i.e. found at position 0)
"positional".find("pos")

# return -1 (i.e. for not found at all)
"positional".find("not there")
```

The same return values are used in many programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

`-1` is used rather than a `False` because the method is intended to return an integer if found.

Comment: `False` **is** an integer - the problem is it's `0`, which is a valid index!